# How do mount tools, helpers, and calls relate?

Tags: filesystems, mount

`man 8 mount` says `mount` uses helpers in `/sbin/` (such as `mount.exfat`, `mount.fuse`, and `mount.ntfs`). `man 2 mount` doesn't mention helpers. The corresponding `umount` pages showed the same thing.

My `ls /sbin | grep mount` shows:

```
mount.cifs
mount.ecryptfs
mount.ecryptfs_private
mount.exfat
mount.exfat-fuse
mount.fuse
mount.lowntfs-3g
mount.ntfs
mount.ntfs-3g
umount.ecryptfs
umount.ecryptfs_private
umount.udisks2
```

- Why doesn't `man 2 mount` mention the helpers?
- What does `mount`/`umount` do with filesystems that don't have a helper?
- Why do filesystems have a helper for `mount`, `umount`, both, or neither?

Answer (score 1):

System manuals were "sectioned" some time ago. The [sections are listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections) for various OS. Section 2 is for "System Calls"; i.e. documentation on how a program requests a service provided by the kernel in this case.

Also note that in `man 2 mount`, it **does** provide for a full range of filesystem types as defined in `/proc/filesystems` - `filesystemtype` is an argument in the `mount` function call. If you compare the list in `/proc/filesystems` to the output of `ls /sbin | grep mount`, you will see some commonality.

And so one way to look at this is that the `mount syscall` does have "helpers" - the "helpers" are the value of the `filesystemtype` argument. Another way to look at it is that **Section 2** of `man mount` is for *system programmers*, whereas `man 8 mount` (or just `man mount`) is for *system users* and *administrators*. The user's interface to the kernel service is through a command named `mount`; system programmers interface to the same kernel service is via the `mount` function.

Something for everyone...

Comment: Why do some filesystems not have a helper, and what does either `mount` do when a helper doesn't exist? For example, virtual filesystems like `proc`, `sysfs`, etc.